# Django concurrency bug handling

Tags: django, database, concurrency

I have an API written in Django that provides user with the list of files that they have. There is also a delete API that can delete a File that the user has. However, there is a bug where a GET request after a deletion still shows the previously deleted object. The GET API uses a filter query on the Files object. While the DELETE API will delete a given file id from the list, by getting and calling .delete().

After googling around, it seems like I need to wrap the database queries into a transaction.atomic block and perform select_for_update() in both of the APIs. Will this solve the issue? By right, if the GET Request is done after receiving the DELETE response it should not ever have this concurrency bug right ? It is only if we sent the requests concurrently. But, select_for_update is locking the database row right? So, will the GET API be able to still read the currently being deleted row?

Is this the correct way of handling, or do I need to somehow change the isolation level of the database. Currently the DB is Postgresql which defaults to "Repeatable Read". After reading around, this is a case of Phantom deletion which needs a SERIALIZABLE Transaction level to resolve ?